# I want to add a check box beside each row in a table dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div  id="div1"></div>
<script>
    var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("id","mytable");
    $("#div1").append(tbl);
    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        //alert(x[i].name);
        //alert(x[i].price);
        var tr="<tr>";
        var chk="<th>"+"<input type="checkbox" />"+"</th>";
        var td1="<td>"+x[i].name+"</td>";
        var td2="<td>"+x[i].mainCategory.name+"</td>";
        var td3="<td>"+x[i].subCategory.name+"</td>";
        var td4="<td>"+x[i].price+"</td>";
        var td5="<td>"+x[i].quantity+"</td></tr>";
        $("#mytable").append(tr+td1+td2+td3+td4+td5); 
    }
</script>
```

I want to add dynamically a check box beside each row and the id is the number of row any help , please .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your checkbox column string should be,

```
var chk="<td><input type='checkbox' id='chk_"+i+"' /></td>";
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of <strike>`var chk="<th>"+"<input type="checkbox" />"+"</th>";`</strike>,

Use `var chk="<th>"+"<input type='checkbox' />"+"</th>";`

Notice that I have replaced `"` by `'` around `checkbox` because you can't use the delimiter `"` inside the string without escaping it, or in this case using single quote instead.

Comment: **Downvoter**, reason?

Comment: Can the downvoter please comment as to why they downvoted.